# Volume Bars from Intraday data in R

Tags: r, plot

I have intraday data of financial assets organised in 1 minute bars such that:

```
                       Price     volume
  0013-09-05 02:01:00  137.38      4049
  0013-09-05 02:02:00  137.38       673
  0013-09-05 02:03:00  137.37       504
```

Now, I want (using R) to sample the Price at  every 1000 stocks trades (i.e.: create volume bars of 1000 or any other quantity for that matter). How can it be done in R? I need this to calculate the VPIN from Easley et al. (2012)

Thank you!

Comment: `sample(c(137.38, 137.38, 137.37), size = 1000, replace=T, prob=c(4049, 673, 504))` could you test if this does what you want?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean with "sample price at every 1000 stock trades". Do you otherwise mean that you have 4 volume bars where all the observations are 137.78 (based on time of 2:01:00 only)

Comment: Maybe show what you would like as output.